# switching setDebugOutput off on esp8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino

This thing is driving me nuts.

I tried to debug my MQTT secure connection on nodecmu. Following some post from year 2015 I was switched on debugging output with `Serial.setDebugOutput(true)`. Now I tried to switch it off with `setDebugOutput(false)` as well as disabled, chose selective output, you name it from the menus:

[image: arduino nodemcu settings]

I tried to do

```
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(false);
```

I also tried

```
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
```

It just keeps printing:

[image: debugging infos]

Posts from year 2015 show that this issue is addressed in some version of arduino/arduino GUI. Where should I look for the versions?

Comment: what happens if you send debug messages to Serial1, but do not connect the console to Serial1 so that the debug messages go into the "bit bucket"

Comment: Hi @jsotola, what a wonderful idea! And you know what? It solved the issue. I have set `Serial.begin(115200);Serial1.setDebugOutput(true);`, told `Tools->Debug Port` to be `Serial1`, and voila! the messages are gone! Will you post this as an answer, so I can set this question as resolved?

Comment: you are in a  better position to post the answer,  because you can provide detailed information about what you had to do, to redirect the debug messages.

Comment: @jsotola, yes I am, once you add your answer, I'll add my three cents through edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot disable the generation of the debug messages, then you could try to redirect the debug messages so that they are not visible on Serial.

As a workaround, send the messages to `Serial1` and keep the console attached to `Serial`.

This may not be an optimum solution, because the messages are still being sent, which takes up some of the processing power and uses up a serial port.

If that does not solve your logging problem, make sure that you also set Serial1 as your logging Serial from the menu:

[image: set up logging serial]